# Performance-Problems with jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

a lot of users of my website report problems with jquery ui dialog. Some IE Users have message that script runs to long time. And some Opera users tell that dialogs all popup on loading the website and everything slows down or they are not able to close them at all. here is the code i use:

```
<?php foreach ($buffs as $own_buff): ?>
<div style="display:none">
    <div id="popup-pos-link-<?php echo $own_buff['id']?>" style="position: relative">
         <img src="<?php echo $html->url("img/Sektor" . $own_buff['sector'] . ".png"); ?>" title="some text" alt="some text" />
         <img id="poscross-<?php echo $own_buff['id']?>" src="<?php echo $html->url('img/cross.png'); ?>" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; position: absolute;left: <?php echo $own_buff['xcoord']; ?>px; top: <?php echo $own_buff['ycoord']; ?>px;" />
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is the code for the links to open dialog:

```
<?php foreach ($buffs as $own_buff): ?>
<a href="#popup-pos-link-<?php echo $own_buff['id']?>" id="pos-link-<?php echo $own_buff['id']?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $html->url('img/lupe.gif')?>" title="<?php echo __('view_map'); ?>" alt="<?php echo __('view_map'); ?>" style="width:16px;height:16px;" />
</a>    
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

and this is the javascript code to create dialog and make click events for them on the links:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[id^=popup-pos-link]').dialog({
          autoOpen: false,
          modal: true,
          width: 'auto'
    });

    $('[id^=pos-link]').click(function(e) {
        $('#popup-' + $(this).attr('id')).dialog("open");
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

At least i was not able to produce error by myself. But users that reported problems have been on Opera or Internet-Explorer and also most of them used windows or ubuntu on 64-Bit.

Does anybody have an idea what kind of Problem could be with that code?

Maybe also important to know that this code is loaded once via ajax into existing div-container.

Best regards
Andi

Comment: If you could strip off the PHP bits and create a jsFiddle with just the HTML markup + Javascript, it would be easier to help.

Comment: How many dialogs are on the page? Do you need to be able to open multiple dialogs at the same time? If not, instead of creating a dialog for each link, create a single dialog template, and fill it in when the user clicks on the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your `$('[id^=popup-pos-link]')` selector is probably in cause, cf. [jQuery's website](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

> However it will be slower than using a class selector so leverage classes, if you can, to group like elements

Fix this easily by assigning classes and selecting by class, like `$('.popup-pos-link')`, same for `.pos-link`

Comment: i will change this selector into class selector. To use this regex selector was just because i had fancybox before i used jquerui dialog. But not sure if it really will solve the problem. But i will wait for furhter user feedback and then i will let u know.

Comment: @Barmar also has a point in his comment. If you create many DOM nodes this could explain the perf problems.